# recurrence for 2nd order Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains

Given that $X_n$ given $X_{n-1},...,X_0$ is Poisson distributed with mean $a+bX_{n-1}+cX_{n-2}$, for $n\geq 2, a>0,b,c\geq 0$.
Define $Y_n=\begin{pmatrix}X_n\\X_{n-1} \end{pmatrix}$. Prove that $Y=(Y_n)_{n\in\mathrm{N}}$ is recurrent if $b+c<1$.

I know that if $X_{n}$ given $X_{n-1},...,X_0$ is Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda=a+bX_{n-1}$, where $a>0,b\geq 0$, then $X=(X_n)_{n\in\mathrm{N_0}}$ is a recurrent M.C & it is recurrent if $b <1$. Can we make use of this fact and extend it to the case of 2nd-order MC as shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove that when $b+c\lt1$ there exists $\lambda\lt1$, $w\gt0$ and a vector $V$ with positive coordinates such that $Z=V^*Y-w$ solves $\mathbb E[Z_{n+1}\mid \mathcal F_n]=\lambda Z_n$.

Comment: Z is one-dimensional or 2-dimensional?

Comment: If V and Y are 2-dimensional vectors what is the dimension of V*Y? Hint: the same as the dimension of w.

Comment: v is row and Y is column?

Comment: Y "is column": this is in your question, no? V "is column" as well: else, how is V*Y supposed to be a real number?

Comment: Hi, just to check... $\lambda$ satisfies the equation $\lambda^2-\lambda b - c = 0$?

Comment: Indeed. $ $ $ $